# Python 2.7/3 PyGame Installation

Tags: python, macos, pygame, pip, homebrew

I am trying to install pygame on my Macbook pro running mavericks.

I have followed the following tutorial in order to install pygame:
"http://dudeslife.com/blog/2014/programming/installing-python-3-3-3-pygame-on-os-x-mavericks/"

I have both followed directions to install pygame under python3 and python 2.7.

Unfortunately, when I run "sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame" I receive the following error.

```
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/imageext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/imageext.o

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-fpBwWg-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Nhafjq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-fpBwWg-build
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/username/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

According to the note I can't set the flags in the compiler to ignore this warning, so I am at a loss. I have been trying to install Pygame for a while now and would appreciate any help.

Best,
Frustrated Beginner Python User

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of breaking changes from Apple to the Xcode command line tools. This is briefly explained [here](https://langui.sh/2014/03/10/wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future-is-a-harsh-mistress/).

A few sites offer a (temporary) workaround for this bug though. Try running:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"
```

in your terminal and then retry the installation. If that doesn't work, there might not be an easy workaround or fix for your problem. Post back with your results though, please!